# How to get connection on spinor bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry

I do not understand, how I get a connection on the spinor bundle from some connection on the $Spin^{\mathbb{C}}$-structure:
Let $M$ be an oriented, Riemannian manifold with a $Spin^{\mathbb{C}}$-structure $P_M$. Then from lifting the Levi-Civita connection, we can get a connection on $P_M$. I then want to know: How can we (out of this connection on $P_M$) obtain a connection on the spinor bundle, which is given by $P_M \times_{Spin^{\mathbb{C}}} V$ where $V$ is the unique irreducible representation $\mathbb{C}l_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Answer (score 2):

I'll also throw [1](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~amt/SpinorBdles.pdf) into the mix here. A personal favourite for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in the first few pages of Chapter 3 in [Dirac Operators in Riemannian Geometry](http://books.google.com/books?id=5RShm9uIa5UC&lpg=PA57&dq=connections%20in%20spinor%20bundles&pg=PA57#v=onepage&q=connections%20in%20spinor%20bundles&f=false) by Thomas Friedrich.